# Transferring Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in VS 2005 using the wizard. In the report I have created an OLE DB connection to a server which has a database 'student'. Now I need to run this report on another computer which has the same database but a different server name. How do I change the connection settings for this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question:
[Setting Crystal Report data source at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591088/setting-crystal-report-data-source-at-runtime)
You need to set the name of the server (the Data Source in ODBC terms) for each table in your report.  If you have subreports, you will need to open each subreport and set each table there as well.  You can also change any other connection settings at the same time.